# how to find sub tagname by using By.tagName in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, unit-testing

i am struggling with find sub tag name 
i want to find "ankit patel" name from using below code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmmhq.png)

i am writing my code for as below

```
  List<WebElement> rows= driver.findElements(By.id("ui-id-2") ); //Printing the size of the rows 
    List<WebElement> lirowsx =  rows.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

      System.out.print(lirowsx .size() +"size "); 

      int s=lirowsx.size();
```

when i am trying to access "ankit patel" using "li" tag then it returns and error message
like 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
i have also tried with xpath but didn't get result.

can you please guide me how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element by first finding it by xpath and then fetching its text.
You can do it like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//strong"));
// Fetching the text
String text = element.getText();
```

Comment: getting error->Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ui-id-11"]/div/div[1]/strong"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Comment: @Pankaj the xpath that is mentioned in your stacktrace is different from the one that i have mentioned in my ans. Please pick the xpath that i have mentioned in my ans

Comment: i have also tried with your xpath but still error returns ->Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@id='ui-id-11']//strong"} (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Comment: @Pankaj i have updated my xpath, please pick the new one and let me know if it works

Comment: still getting same issue ->Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//strong"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Answer (score 0):

If the `li` element id is unique then

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='ui-id-11']//strong"));
```

or

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='ui-id-11']/div/div/strong"));
```

and to get the text

```
String text = element.getText();
```

Feel free to post any more errors you see...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@id='ui-id-11']/div/div/strong"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Comment: still getting same issue ->Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='ui-menu-item']//strong"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Comment: try `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);`                       
`String text = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@id='ui-id-11']//strong"))).getText();` before getting the text because it may be possible that element is not available by the time you access it.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //li[@id='ui-id-11']//strong (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)

Comment: @Pankaj, has this application got public access or it is internal only?

Comment: its public but its only access on UK and India so want you use?

Comment: I should be able to access it, what is the url?